# InvalidArgumentError Error when using tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0 to build tf.keras.models.Model with two models generator and discriminator

Tags: tensorflow

I am building a conditional generative adversarial network with tf.keras APIs. I am getting a strange error when using tf.keras.models.Model saying that the output of the first model, generator, is not passed to the input of the second model, discriminator.

I have tried downgrading and upgrading tensorflow versions both nightly and stable and release 2 alpha, but no way.

I have debugged the outputs of the generator to make sure it matches the inputs of the discriminator in shape.

My code is available completely on https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q1q37ZU3V94NP9T-G0gQTxLnyOjqKEZd

The issue I am getting is assumably related to:

```
generator = build_generator()
discriminator = build_discriminator()

GLR = 0.0009  # generator
DLR = 0.0001  # discriminator


discriminator.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=DLR), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


# condition
c = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(cond_len,))

# noise
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(noise_len,))

# freeze discriminator
discriminator.trainable = False

# output
z = generator([c, x])
out = discriminator([c, z])

# GAN
gan = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[c, x], outputs=out)


gan.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=GLR), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The error occurs when running this snippet

```
  for p, row in enumerate(parsed_train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)):

    sz = row['img'].shape[0]

    if sz != BATCH_SIZE:
      continue

    # train generator

    # concatenate face + age + noise
    c1 = row['enc']
    c2 = tf.cast(row['age'], tf.float32)
    c = tf.concat([c1, c2], axis=-1)
    x = tf.random.normal((sz, noise_len,))

    # train
    print(c.shape, x.shape, y_true.shape)
    loss_1, acc_1 = gan.train_on_batch([c, x], y_true)
```

This is the outputs errors I am getting:

```
(16, 136) (16, 3072) (16,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-fe427c1a744f> in <module>()
     82     # train
     83     print(c.shape, x.shape, y_true.shape)
---> 84     loss_1, acc_1 = gan.train_on_batch([c, x], y_true)
     85 
     86     batch_loss = float(tf.reduce_mean(loss_1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1254       if reset_metrics:
   1255         self._make_train_function()
-> 1256         outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
   1257       else:
   1258         self._make_fit_function()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3215         value = math_ops.cast(value, tensor.dtype)
   3216       converted_inputs.append(value)
-> 3217     outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
   3218     return nest.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_structure,
   3219                                  [x.numpy() for x in outputs])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    556       raise TypeError("Keyword arguments {} unknown. Expected {}.".format(
    557           list(kwargs.keys()), list(self._arg_keywords)))
--> 558     return self._call_flat(args)
    559 
    560   def _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args)
    625     # Only need to override the gradient in graph mode and when we have outputs.
    626     if context.executing_eagerly() or not self.outputs:
--> 627       outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
    628     else:
    629       self._register_gradient()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args)
    413             attrs=("executor_type", executor_type,
    414                    "config_proto", config),
--> 415             ctx=ctx)
    416       # Replace empty list with None
    417       outputs = outputs or None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     64     else:
     65       message = e.message
---> 66     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     67   except TypeError as e:
     68     if any(ops._is_keras_symbolic_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_20' with dtype float and shape [?,32,32,3]
     [[{{node input_20}}]]
     [[GroupCrossDeviceControlEdges_0/training_15/Adam/Adam/Const/_63]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_130833]
```

Comment: Have you tried some smth to debug your code. As error states it lack some value. Maybe some of relevant tensors is empty. Please try to localize problem, in present state it's arguably too broad

Comment: I am quite doubtful that this is an issue in Tensorflow core where the graph is disconnected when linking two models together as above.